# SOAP WSDL Location URL incorrect when front-end URL different from admin URL

Tags: magento-1.9, soap-api-v2

I have a Magento v1.9.3.x site where the SOAP calls are not working.

There are several factors about our environment that might cause the problem:

- we use a different subdomin for front-end website vs admin site
- we use a load balancer in front of multiple servers

The main problem seems to be that when you request the WSDL via the front-end, it returns the admin URL in the < soap:address location="" /> element.

This is what is happening step by step:

1. The client calls 'https://www.magentohost.com/api/v2_soap?wsdl=1'
2. The server returns XML containing < soap:address location="https://admin.magentohost.com/index.php/api/v2_soap/index/?SID=88888888888888888888888888888888"/ >
3. Calling 'https://admin.magentohost.com/index.php/api/v2_soap/index/?SID=88888888888888888888888888888888'
   returns a 301 redirect back to https://www.magentohost.com/ (with no
   query path or parameters)
4. Obviously that will not work, so the client shows an error message saying 'SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from
   https://admin.magentohost.com/index.php/api/v2_soap/index/?SID=88888888888888888888888888888888

Does anyone have a fix for this problem?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this problem?